# How do I set the value of a column be a result of a SQL query using one of the columns of the same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

Table 1 : Users

Has columns `id`,`Name`,`institution`

Institution is a sting showing institution name.

Table 2:  Institutions.

Has columns `id`,`institution`,`count`

I need the `count` column to be recording the number of rows in table 1 where `institution` is same as the `institution` in each row of Table 2. This should happen for all the rows of Table 2.

Please help me get the right MySQL queries or table relations to achieve this.

Comment: just join on institution?

Comment: Why store `count` in the DB? Just use SQL to count your results as you query.

Comment: The reason why I am storing count is because I would like to get a statistical result of each institution with the respective student number.

Answer (score 1):

`Join` both the tables on `instutions` and get the count like below

```
select i.institution,
X.ins_count
from  Institutions i
left join
(
select institution,
count(*) as ins_count
from Users
group by institution
) X on i.institutions = X.institutions
```

Comment: Rahul,Sorry I don't get this clearly, could you make it simpler?

Comment: Sure, the inner query within `()` is getting the count grouping the institutions and then in outer query you are getting columns from both table joining on institutions column. the part under `()` is derived table. Again, no point in storing the `count` in table as you can get it in query and do any calculation on it.

Comment: To handle the case when there are no rows in user for a particular institution, this would need to be an outer join.

Comment: @spencer7593, correct but without seeing his actual schema/design; it would be kind of speculation. that's the very same reason kept it as inner join. Edited.

Comment: @Rahul: This isn't dependent on the schema design; the actual DDL won't tell you if every row in `institution` has at least one corresponding row in `users`. Absent that specification, it's better to design the SQL to handle that case; otherwise, we could leave a row in institution with a non-zero count; it's better to ensure that every row in institution is updated, and a row is assigned a zero value for `count` when `users` table is empty.

Comment: +1 @Rahul: I agree with you; the INNER JOIN operation will work fine,  **if** we are guaranteed there's at least one row in `users` for each `institution` in the `institutions` table (i.e. we won't ever have a zero `count`.)

Comment: Guys, the institution table contains about 100 institutions. Currently, there are only about 20 covered, so basically some will have a zero count. The `count` field needs to be edited automatically a user signs up by selecting one of the institutions in the `institutions` table. (I can do this by running the code at completion of each sign Up). The concept of inner Join hasn't sank so well for me.

Answer (score 0):

this question doesn't have a lot of detail but from what I understand you just want to do this.

```
UPDATE TABLE institutions,
    (SELECT 
        i.id,
        COUNT(u.id) as user_count
    FROM Users u
    JOIN Institutions i on i.institution = u.institution
    GROUP BY i.institution) as temp
SET institutions.count = temp.user_count 
WHERE temp.id = institutions.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
UPDATE institutions i
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT u.institution
              , COUNT(1) AS user_cnt 
           FROM users u
          GROUP BY u.institution
       ) c
    ON c.institution = i.institution
   SET i.count = IFNULL(c.user_cnt,0)
```

The inline view (aliased as c) gets a count of users for each "institution". This result is outer joined to institutions. (We reference the result from that inline view query like it was a table; MySQL actually refers to the inline view as a "derived table".

We assign the value derived `user_cnt` value to the `count` column, and substituting 0 for NULL (which will happen if there are no users in a given "institution".)

To see this in action BEFORE you run the update, you can run a similar SELECT (remove the SET clause and change the `UPDATE` keyword to be `SELECT <expression_list> FROM`, optionally add an `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT i.institution
     , i.count               AS old_count
     , IFNULL(c.user_cnt,0)  AS new_count
  FROM institutions i
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT u.institution
              , COUNT(1) AS user_cnt 
           FROM users u
          GROUP BY u.institution
       ) c
    ON c.institution = i.institution
 ORDER BY i.institution
```

---

As another possible approach to achieve the same result, but with (likely) less efficiency (if this is actually valid), would be to use a correlated subquery to return the value:

```
UPDATE institutions i
   SET i.count = ( SELECT COUNT(1) 
                     FROM users u
                    WHERE u.institution = i.institution
                 )
```

I know that approach "works" in a SELECT statement. I expect it to work in an UPDATE statement, but I haven't tested that. Equivalent SELECT would be:

```
SELECT i.institution
     , i.count AS old_count
     , ( SELECT COUNT(1) 
           FROM users u
          WHERE u.institution = i.institution
        ) AS new_count
  FROM institutions i
```

Absent any compelling reason to use a correlated subquery, I'd avoid that and go with the JOIN operation instead.

Comment: You guy @Spencer, approach worked with `UPDATE` , and it has updated my statistics so well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @BrianNyagol, then consider acceting the answer to show your appreciation.

Comment: How do i do that? They say I must have 15 reputations to mark an answer as useful